# Biggest resolution for art assets for mobile games

Tags: graphics, art, assets, resolution

I have created a game, and now I need to integrate graphics and distribute it for iOS and Android devices. As there are crazy number of screen resolutions, I think I should have just 3 set of art assets `HDR`, `HD = HDR x 0.5`, `SD = HDR * 0.25` and in run-time my game will choose the smallest asset for the device that can cover the screen. Cause otherwise I would have more than 10 set of assets to cover the majority of Android and iOS devices because of so many densities and aspect ratios. So I need to decide which will be the biggest asset size. Till now iPad Retina size was the reference (2048 x 1536), I guess. But after iPhone 6+ was issued with asset resolution equal to 2208 x 1242, I don't know what should be the `HDR` asset resolution. Maybe 2208x1536? to be able to cover any mobile device (all tablets and phones) screen?

Comment: How is this fundamentally different from your [last question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/84333/spritesheet-size)? We can't tell you what graphics resolution to pick, and we can't answer a question scoped as broadly as "mobile devices" because they change all the time.

Comment: @JoshPetrie This one is asking how big I should ask artist to draw the images. In the other one I ask how big I create a spritesheet so that devices could load them.

Comment: I think the question is adequate and there seem to be no other questions that are answering the issue - what should your assets resolutions be, and should you have separate for different iPhones or have one and scale/upscale them. In both cases, what should the assets resolution be? Example: for the second case, which iPhone resolution should be default assets resolution so that we scale best?

Answer (score 2):

For Android, Don't go over 2048x2048, as some devices do no support them (including nexus 10).

Comment: That's not only applicable to Android. A lot of the Apple devices only go up to `2048x2048` texture size. Some of the first devices (iPhone, iPhone 3G) even had an upper limit of `1024x1024`.